# Como otimizar o jogo batalha naval em JAVA?

Tags: java, otimização

**Não sei se isso é permitido aqui no site, então caso eu esteja quebrando alguma regra me avisem!**

Comecei, recentemente, a aprender a linguagem JAVA. Fiz um jogo de batalha naval (humano x computador) usando tudo o que aprendi até agora e gostaria de ouvir opiniões de programadores mais experientes sobre o game, a fim de melhorar meus conhecimentos.

Alguns pontos como o que você teria feito de diferente? Como você otimizaria o código já existente? Cometi alguma redundância ou escrevi mais do que o necessário?

**Como pensei a programação do jogo?**

Criei duas *arrays* 5x5. Uma armazena o tabuleiro do jogo. Ela é iniciada com o valor padrão 0 para todos os elementos. Com um método, faço ser sorteado 3 desses elementos, que passarão a representar a posição dos barcos a serem afundados. À eles atribuo o valor 1. A outra array armazena as posições onde o jogador disparou, 0 simboliza uma área onde ainda não se atacou e 1 uma área onde se atacou.

Para exibir o tabuleiro, cruzo as duas *arrays* em uma verificação. Onde ainda não se atacou, consta como "~", onde se atacou e não há navio como "*" e onde se atacou e afundou um navio como "X". Criei um método para que a cada turno seja exibida uma dica informando se a quantidade de navios existentes na linha e na coluna do último disparo realizado.

**Código**:

**BatalhaNaval.java**

```
package batalhanaval;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BatalhaNaval
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Tabuleiro tab = new Tabuleiro();
        char option; //Opção do menu principal

        do
        {
            showMenu();
            option = entrada.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            switch(option)
            {
                case '1': //Novo jogo
                {
                    initGame(entrada, tab);
                    break;
                }
                case '2':
                {
                    System.out.println("O seu objetivo no jogo é afundar os 3 navios inimigos que encontram-se no seu litoral.\n"
                            + "Para fazer um disparo, informe a posição(linha e coluna) do seu mapa na qual deseja lançar o míssel.\n"
                            + "O símbolo ~ indica uma área ainda não conhecida.\n"
                            + "O símbolo * indica uma área na qual você disparou e não havia nenhum navio.\n"
                            + "O símbolo X indica uma área onde você afundou um navio inimigo.\n"
                            + "A cada disparo realizado você receberá uma dica informando se há navios na linha e na coluna nas quais você realizou o disparo.");
                    break;
                }
                case '3': //Recorde
                {
                    if(tab.recorde == 1000)
                    {
                       System.out.println("<Recorde atual: nenhum>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       System.out.println("<Recorde atual: " + tab.recorde + " turnos>");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case '4':
                {
                    System.out.println("Finalizando...");
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    System.out.println("Opção inválida!");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n");         
        }while(option != '4');

    }
    //Método que retorna true caso a String seja um número inteiro
    public static boolean isInt(String str)
    {
        try 
        {  
            Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
            return true;     
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
        {  
            return false;         
        }  
    }
    //Main menu
    public static void showMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("Bem vindo ao jogo <Batalha Naval>!!! (Criado por Talendar)\nEscolha uma opção:");
        System.out.println("1 - Novo jogo");
        System.out.println("2 - Tutorial");
        System.out.println("3 - Recorde");
        System.out.println("4 - Sair");
    }
    //Jogo
    public static void initGame(Scanner entrada, Tabuleiro tab)
    {
        String linha = ""; //As variáveis linha e coluna foram criadas como String para poderem ser submetidas a checagem do método isInt(str) localizado abaixo.
        String coluna = "";

        tab.initTab();
        tab.initShips();
        do
        {
            System.out.println("\n");
            //Exibe a dica a partir do segundo turno
            if(tab.turno > 1)
            {
                tab.dica(Integer.parseInt(linha), Integer.parseInt(coluna));
            }
            System.out.println();

            //Exibe o tabuleiro em seu estado atual
            tab.printTab();

            //Pede a linha
            System.out.print("Linha:");
            linha = entrada.next();
            while(!isInt(linha))
            {
                System.out.println("Apenas números inteiros de 1 a 5!\nLinha:");
                linha = entrada.next();
            }
            while(Integer.parseInt(linha) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(linha) > 5)
            {
                System.out.println("Apenas números inteiros de 1 a 5!\nLinha:");
                linha = entrada.next();
            }

            //Pede a coluna
            System.out.print("Coluna:");
            coluna = entrada.next();
            while(!isInt(coluna))
            {
                System.out.println("Apenas números inteiros de 1 a 5!\nColuna:");
                coluna = entrada.next();
            }
            while(Integer.parseInt(coluna) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(coluna) > 5)
            {
                System.out.println("Apenas números inteiros de 1 a 5!\nColuna:");
                coluna = entrada.next();
            }
            System.out.println("\n\n");

            //Tiro
            tab.tiro(Integer.parseInt(linha), Integer.parseInt(coluna));
            System.out.println();

        }while(tab.acertos != 3);
        System.out.println("\nVOCÊ DERROTOU O INIMIGO!!!! Turnos: " + tab.turno);
        if(tab.turno < tab.recorde)
        {
            tab.recorde = tab.turno;
            System.out.println("\nNOVO RECORDE (" + tab.recorde + ")!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Tabuleiro.java**

```
/* Água não descoberta(~)
   Água vazia(*): 0
   Navio(X): 1
*/
package batalhanaval;
import java.util.Random;

public class Tabuleiro
{
    int turno = 1; //Turno em questão
    int acertos = 0; //Armazena o número de acertos
    int recorde = 1000; //Armazena o recorde
    int[][] tab = new int[5][5]; //Tabuleiro
    int[][] tiros = new int[5][5]; //Armazeana as posições dos tiros dados: 0 para área desconhecida e 1 para área onde se atirou.

    // Inicia o tabuleiro com o valor padrão 0
    public void initTab()
    {
        acertos = 0;
        turno = 1;
        for(int[] i: tab)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i.length; j++)
            {
                i[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //Sorteia os navios
    public void initShips()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int i; //Linha
        int j; //Coluna

        for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
        {
            do
            {
                i = rand.nextInt(5);
                j = rand.nextInt(5);  
            }while(tab[i][j] != 0);
            tab[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    //Mostra o tabuleiro de inteiros
    public void printTabInt()
    {
        System.out.print("     (1)  (2)  (3)  (4)  (5)\n\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("("+ (i+1) + ")  ");
            for(int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" "+tab[i][j]+"   ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
    //Mostra o tabuleiro de jogo
    public void printTab()
    {
        System.out.print("     (1)  (2)  (3)  (4)  (5)\n\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("("+ (i+1) + ")  ");
            for(int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(tiros[i][j] == 1)
                {
                    if(tab[i][j] == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.print(" X   ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print(" *   ");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" ~   ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
    //Tiro
    public void tiro(int linha, int coluna)
    {
        if(tiros[linha-1][coluna-1] == 0) //Checa se já foi dado tiro na posição fornecida
        {
            tiros[linha-1][coluna-1] = 1; //Muda o valor da posição fornecida para que conste como uma área atirada
            if(tab[linha-1][coluna-1] == 1) //Checa se há um navio na posição fornecida
            {
                System.out.println("Você afundou um navio inimigo!!!");
                acertos++; //Aumenta +1 em acertos
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Você atingiu a água...");
            }
            turno++; //Avança o turno
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Você já atirou nessa posição!");
        }
    }
    //Dica: informa o turno e se há alguma navio na linha e na coluna do último tiro disparado
    public void dica(int linha, int coluna)
    {
        System.out.println("Turno: " + turno);

        int countL = 0;
        for(int i: tab[linha-1])
        {
            if(i == 1)
            {
                countL++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Dica: há " + countL + " navio(s) na linha " + linha);

        int countC = 0;
        for(int[] i: tab)
        {
            if(i[coluna-1] == 1)
            {
                countC++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("      há " + countC + " navio(s) na coluna " + coluna);
    }
}
```

Comment: Se você puder re-escrever a pergunta em inglês, sugiro mover ela para http://codereview.stackexchange.com, esse site foi feito com o objetivo de revisar códigos nas perguntas. Você também ainda pode fazer pergunta sobre algo específico em relação à performance no StackOverflow (pt, es, en, jp, etc)

Comment: Ou pode aguardar ver se alguém pode ajudar, já que a pergunta está totalmente dentro das regras e do escopo deste site. O texto poderia ser mais organizado para favorecer quem for tentar ajudar. Separar cada parte em um parágrafo já ajudaria, mas poderia se colocar no lugar de quem for ajudar em um código que ele nunca viu e tentar passar a informação de um jeito melhor.

Comment: Eu concordo com o @bigown: a sua pergunta faz parte do escopo do site. Só que ela está difícil de ser respondida de forma objetiva. Vc menciona "otimização" (o que, por princípio, eu entendo "desempenho"), mas o seu jogo é bem simples e não parece ter qualquer problema grave de desempenho. Sobre a forma como você implementou, ela está correta e te serve à sua necessidade *atual*.

Comment: Aí você pergunta se alguém teria feito algo diferente. Possivelmente. Mas uma pergunta que talvez seja mais apropriada seria: como tornar esse código mais fácil de ser evoluído? (para incluir embarcações com formatos diferentes de apenas uma célula, por exemplo). Aí a pergunta deixa de ser tanto opinativa, mas ainda fica ampla. Eu começaria por representar cada navio por uma classe e implementar nessa classe a detecção de "colisão" (se um tiro atingiu ou não). Pode ser um bom exercício pra vc, e quem sabe até gerar outras perguntas suas aqui no site. :)

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você esteja pesquisando para ter mais conhecimentos sobre boas práticas de código, orientação a objetos, testes automatizados e assim por diante.

Sugiro que você mesmo tenha o senso crítico de auto-avaliar seu código a fim de procurar falhas. Bons programadores aprendem com o próprio erro.

Para tentar elevar seu conhecimento, vou sugerir alguns temas com links para você se aprofundar no assunto. Segue alguns:

## TDD (Test Driven Design):

Desenvolvimento de software baseado em testes. Você evolui o seu código apenas para o teste passar. Isso facilita com que você construa um melhor design da sua arquitetura e objetos, garantindo simplicidade, baixo acoplamento e cobertura automática dos seus testes.

## Orientação a Objeto

Garante que seu sistema possua classes com um único propósito e que se comunicam entre si, garantindo sua manutenibilidade, usabilidade e evolução do sistema.
Caso se interesse pelo assunto, criei 10 regras para garantir que seu código siga as boas práticas de orientação a objetos baseada no livro "The ThoughtWorks Anthology: Essays on Software".

https://github.com/matheusmessora/OOP-MANIFESTO

---

Vou citar alguns exemplos do seu código que infrinja algumas regras:

**Regra 4**: Apenas 1 ponto por linha
Melhora a legibilidade do código.

O trecho de código abaixo viola essa regra, dificultando sua leitura.

```
tab.dica(Integer.parseInt(linha), Integer.parseInt(coluna));
```

Uma melhor prática seria
Integer linha = Integer.parseInt(linha);
Integer coluna = Integer.parseInt(coluna);
tab.dica(linha, coluna);

**Regra 9**: Método deve possuir apenas 7 linhas de código.
Isso garante que seus métodos tenham alta coesão, ou seja, fazem apenas o que devem fazer, e nada mais.
Seu método *printTab* por exemplo infringe a regra.

---

Para finalizar, devo acrescentar que todo método deve ficar no infinitivo. Isso é uma boa prática adotada em muitas linguagens orientadas a objeto.
Neste caso, o método *tab.dica* deveria ser alterado para *tab.exibirDica(...)*

Comment: `Bons programadores aprendem com o próprio erro`, verdade, os maus não só insistem no erro, mas nem reconhecem quando estão cometendo. Maus programadores seguem regras, não entendem pra que elas servem, outro vão ainda mais longe e inventam regras completamente sem fundamento. TDD não tem nada a ver com a pergunta. E o que faz construir sistemas melhores é conhecimento real e experiência qualitativa. Sem isso pode usar a ferramenta que quiser que vai sair coisa errada. OOP não garante nada, muito menos o que foi afirmado. Saber fazer sistemas corretamente e aplicar esse conhecimento ajuda...

Comment: ...alguma coisa, mas também não garante. OOP não é panaceia e na verdade como poucas pessoas sabem fazer certo, tem mais prejudicado do que ajudado. Existem outras ferramentas com objetivos semelhantes. Bons programadores as conhecem e aplicam a melhor para cada caso, não acham que uma só ferramenta resolve tudo. Na minha opinião a resposta mais prejudica que ajuda por colocar coisas que não tem relevância para a pergunta, tendenciosamente com base em informações sem fundamento e universalmente consideradas errôneas.

Comment: Me desculpe, mas essas 10 regras, além de, no geral, não ter nada a ver com OOP, são todas erradas, algumas por um pequeno detalhe, outras com erro grave, até porque está dizendo para fazer o oposto do que deve. Todas são ruins porque elas estabelecem o que fazer sem um contexto. Nenhuma faz sentido no uso geral, algumas fazem sentido em algo muito específico, tão específico que jamais poderia ser usada em uma texto que tenta dizer o que é bom ou não. Não vou ficar debatendo o assunto, meu objetivo é só alertar as pessoas que essa resposta prega uma vontade pessoal e não algo consolidado..

Comment: As "10 regras" são baseadas do "Object calisthenics" de Jeff Bay. São regras para serem praticadas para melhorar suas skills em programação, e sim, não devem ser usadas em todo projeto. Existem N+1 solução para a pergunta acima, o que eu quis propor aqui era abrir a mente do questionador para novos temas, a fim de elevar os conhecimentos dele.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2081135/core-java/object-calisthenics-change-the-way-you-code.html

Comment: Note que lá não fala em OOP. Alguns dos erros mais graves não estão lá. Mas ainda tem regras tolas sem explicação. O problema é que muita gente lê essas listas, não sabem nada de nada e acreditam que elas são boas e seguem cegamente porque é o que elas têm à mão. Embora a intenção seja ajudar, muitas vezes acaba prejudicando.

Comment: Sem entrar no mérito da qualidade da tal lista, eu discordo da aplicação da regra 4 no exemplo que você forneceu. Primeiramente, a linha do jeito que está é suficientemente clara pra quem conhece a linguagem. Em segundo lugar, se a questão é esforço (de digitar `Integer.parseInt` para cada parâmetro) porque o método espera um tipo diferente do utilizado, uma "solução" melhor (mais clara) seria implementar uma sobrecarga do método `dica` da classe `tab`. Ou usar o tipo de dado correto. Ou já convertê-lo no momento que ele é produzido. Definitivamente, a troca que você sugere é 6 por meia dúzia.

Comment: Aliás, a sua regra 4 é conflitante com a sua regra 9, porque ao se seguir a regra 4 se está justamente aumentando o número de linhas (ou de colunas, se vc optar por colocar *tudo* numa única linha)  - o que, pelo que afirma a regra 9, tende a diminuir a "coesão" (cujo significado que você emprega não está claro).